# Working example of event tag in jsdoc3

Tags: node.js, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Can someone please give me an example on how to use the @event tag properly.

I've looked at the jsdoc3 documentation here:
http://usejsdoc.org/tags-event.html
but I could not get it working.

I am using nodejs, and I have a module in MyClass/index.js which exports a constructor by the name of MyClass:

```
module.exports = MyClass;
myClass = function () { ... };
```

and I have tried to add

```
/**
 * Snowball event.
 * @event MyClass#snowball
 */
```

In the compiled docs, `snowball` appears in the global list of events, but when I click on it, it tells me

```
The requested URL /{path-to-my-docs}/MyClass.html was not found on this server.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

```
/**
 * @class
 */
function Blah() {
}

/**
 * @event Blah#something
 * @type {Object}
 * @property {integer} some_field Represents something or other.
 */
```

Comment: Does the JSDoc block for it have to go after the initial class declaration?

Comment: I've never tried to put it before the initial class declaration, but I don't think there would be a problem.

Comment: It does; JSDoc refused to properly link classes up and such so I ended up switching to YUIDoc. JSDoc is way too unpredictable.

Comment: I tried it using a custom class as a parameter type. It didn't like that.

Comment: I use custom classes as parameter types all the time. No problem.